# generated TinyURL doesn't work on Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, tinyurl

I am working in a registration module of an application, using a web service returning a generated `TinyURL` corresponding to the new user. 
This `TinyUrl` gives to the user the access to the platform, by `WebView`.

**Problem :** 
The `WebView` works very well with any URL but not with the  `TinyURL` . The `TinyURL` works well on other browsers. Did I miss something?

**Java definition and configuration of the `WebView` :**

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    browser.loadUrl(myTinyUrl);
```

**XML definition of the `WebView` :**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvBrowser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Thanks for your time and help. Every suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What does the URL look like? Does it start with `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: `Web page not available` . I think you gave me the solution, my URL is `www....` , I will try to add `http://` before loading it in the `WebView`. I test it and come back

Comment: you can add it as answer , and I will accept it, for people who has the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` URLs should start with either `http://` or `https://`. A URL starting with `www...` typically shows the standard Android 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to fix URL errors, like `http://` or `www...`, before loading it :

```
/**
 * fix the URL by adding missing "www." and "http://"
 * 
 * @param url
 * @return fixed url
 */
public static String fixUrl(String url) {
    if (!(url == null || url.length() == 0)){
        if (!url.startsWith("www.") && !url.startsWith("http://")) {
            url = "www." + url;
        }
        if (!url.startsWith("http://")) {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
    }
    return url;
}
```